# How to solve element type invalid error in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and I am trying to return a generic button component. The button is supposed to show one of three different icons, either "DeleteIcon", "AddIcon" or "EditIcon". The specified button type is specified as "buttonType" in the input of the IconButton function.

However I keep getting "react-dom.development.js:24036 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string"-error

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add';
import EditIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';

export default function IconButton({ handler, text, color, fill, buttonType }) {
  let Icon;

  switch (buttonType) {
    case 'DeleteIcon':
      Icon = <DeleteIcon />;
      break;
    case 'AddIcon':
      Icon = <AddIcon />;
      break;
    case 'EditIcon':
      Icon = <EditIcon />;
      break;
    default:
      return null;
  }

  return (
    <Button onClick={handler} variant={fill ? 'contained' : 'outlined'} color={color}>
      <Icon />
      {text}
    </Button>
  );
}
```

```
import React from 'react';
import GithubComponent from '../components/GithubComponent';
import IconButton from '../components/buttons/IconButton';
import Button from '../components/buttons/Button';

const LandingPage = () => (
  <div>
    <IconButton text="Hello!" color="red" fill="contained" buttonType="DeleteIcon" />
  </div>
);

export default LandingPage;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`icon` already holds the `ReactElement`, just render it.

Refer to [`introduction to JSX`](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) for more information of what `JSX` is behind the scenes.

Also, you can map `buttonType` to a component using an object:

```
const ICONS = {
  'DeleteIcon': <DeleteIcon />,
  'AddIcon': <AddIcon />,
  'EditIcon': <EditIcon />
}

export default function IconButton({ handler, text, color, fill, buttonType }) {
  return (
    <Button onClick={handler} variant={fill ? 'contained' : 'outlined'} color={color}>
      {ICONS[buttonType]}
      {text}
    </Button>
  );
}
```

---

```
export default function IconButton({ handler, text, color, fill, buttonType }) {
  let Icon;
  switch(buttonType) {
  // Icon = ...
  }

  return (
    <Button onClick={handler} variant={fill ? 'contained' : 'outlined'} color={color}>
  //  v render the component
      {Icon}
      {text}
    </Button>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so so much! You are amazing, I was sitting with this for hours and did not see that

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use JSX in a variable that is already a JSX.

Change

```
  return (
    <Button onClick={handler} variant={fill ? 'contained' : 'outlined'} color={color}>
      <Icon /> // Trying to render a component that is already a react element
      {text}
    </Button>
  );
```

To

```
  return (
    <Button onClick={handler} variant={fill ? 'contained' : 'outlined'} color={color}>
      {Icon} // Rendering the react element
      {text}
    </Button>
  );
```

Or what you can do is get the element in the switch and then render it with JSX.

```
export default function IconButton({ handler, text, color, fill, buttonType }) {
  let Icon;

  switch (buttonType) {
    case 'DeleteIcon':
      Icon = DeleteIcon; // Only getting the Component
      break;
    case 'AddIcon':
      Icon = AddIcon; // Only getting the Component
      break;
    case 'EditIcon':
      Icon = EditIcon; // Only getting the Component
      break;
    default:
      return null;
  }

  return (
    <Button onClick={handler} variant={fill ? 'contained' : 'outlined'} color={color}>
      {Icon && <Icon />}  // You can pass any prop to the component here
      {text}
    </Button>
  );
}
```